# 100% viewidth (vw) in Chrome not working?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, viewport-units

I was trying to reimplement this [codepen](https://codepen.io/lassediercks/pen/VMqMBm) and I've been noticing that the vw declaration is acting weird for chrome. Whenever I'm running this code on my local server, even though I declared that GalleryGrid should have 100vw, it is not sizing properly in only chrome. Other browsers like Firefox and Safari are working fine. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Chrome
[image: Added red borders to help see each item. But notice how the items in GalleryGrid do not fill up the entire div "front"]

Safari/Firefox
[image: Items are filling up the div "front" completely]

**HTML**

```
<div class="front margin">
  <GalleryGrid>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </GalleryGrid>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    GalleryGrid{
      --content-width: 100vw;
      --gutter: 1.5em;
      --columns: 1;
      --width-size: calc(
        ( var(--content-width) - (var(--gutter) * (var(-- 
      columns) - 1))
        ) / var(--columns)
      );
      --row-size: calc(
        ((var(--width-size) * 3)/ 2));
      display: grid;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: var(--content-width);
      grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columns), 1fr);
      grid-auto-rows: var(--row-size);
      grid-column-gap: var(--gutter);
      grid-row-gap: var(--gutter);
    }

    .item {
      position: relative;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12),
                  0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
     }
   .front {
     font-family: Noto Sans, Arial, sans-serif;
     padding: 3em 0;
     margin: 0;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
   }
    .margin{
        margin-left: 4%!important;
        margin-right: 4%!important;
    }
```

Comment: a cache issue? .

Comment: I've deleted my cache multiple times. I added pictures to help visualize more easily if that helps more

Answer (score 0):

You have `GalleryGrid` sitting inside a container with class `margin` which has margin-left and right. Those are being added to the sides since you set the width of `GalleryGrid` to 100% not 100vw

Comment: Well I need the class 'margin' because I don't want `GalleryGrid` to actual expand the entire webscreen. How do you suggest that I get GalleryGrid to expand 100% of the parent div? When I set `--content-width` to 100% the height is not being calculated.

Comment: Oops sorry I misunderstood your question. I'm not sure if this will work, but could you try adding ```width: 100%``` to your ```front``` div?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is over 4 years old, but I experienced an issue with my web pages rocking back and forth slightly on Chrome but not on other browsers.  I eventually discovered that the body is set to 100vw.  From what I can see (I tested this) is that Chrome reports 100vw as the width of the window including the space used by the vertical scroll bar... if your page fits vertically into the screen area and there is no scroll bar, the left-right rocking goes away.  100% actually reports the space minus the width of the scroll bar, so for actual width work I'd say 100vw is probably a bad practice for Chrome.